# simple FormControl on angular

Tags: javascript, angular

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    private myForm: FormGroup;

    constructor() {
        this.myForm = new FormGroup({
            fname: new FormGroup({ fname: new FormControl('', Validators.required) })            
        });
    }   
}

<div [formGroup]="myForm">
    name:
    <input type="text" formControlName="fname">
</div>
```

but on page rendering I'm getting

> ERROR TypeError: control.registerOnChange is not a function
>       at setUpControl (forms.es5.js:1842)

Answer (score 0):

You have a nested formgroup, you need to mark `formGroupName="fname"` in your template:

```
<div [formGroup]="myForm">
  <div formGroupName="fname">
    <input type="text" formControlName="fname">
  </div>
</div>
```

Also you are using same name for formgroup and formcontrol, I suggest you use unique names.

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f7dqkc?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what you want.

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    private myForm: FormGroup;

    constructor() {
        this.myForm = new FormGroup({
             fname: new FormControl('', Validators.required)       
        });
    }   
}

<div [formGroup]="myForm">
    name:
    <input type="text" formControlName="fname">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking something like this

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    private myForm: FormGroup;

    constructor() {
        this.myForm = new FormGroup({
             name: new FormGroup(
              { 
                fname: new FormControl('', Validators.required) }),   
                lname: new FormControl('', Validators.required) })     
              }
      );
    }   
}

<div [formGroup]="myForm">
  <div formGroupName="name">
    <input type="text" formControlName="fname">
    <input type="text" formControlName="lname">
  </div>
</div>
```